# The generated route files of play framework are re-generated automatically, even when there is no changes in conf/routes

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.6

We're working with play framework 2.6.21 (but we're able to reproduce it with play 2.6.19 ).

Sometimes (the problem appears quite randomly), our play application starts to recompile and reload on every changes made in the `public` folder.

After a (not so) quick investigation, when play starts to behave like this, I can kill play, restart `sbt` and then type `compile` multiple times, without doing anything in between, and each time, play recompile some files.

A `last compile` commands shows that the files that changed are the generated route files (Routes.scala, RoutesPrefix.scala,  etc.). A `ls -l` shows that those files were effectively updated. But the file `conf/routes` shows no changes.

Here I'm stuck, I don't know how to investigate further.

How can I know why those routes files are updated? And what is updating them? Which `sbt` command can I type to know why a task was executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question, if anybody has the same problem in the future:

we had in fact 2 route file:
`conf/routes` and `conf/apps.routes` , `conf/routes` contains the line

`-> /apps apps.Routes`

In those file, we 2 routes referencing the same controller, but different action. That's what caused the problem

Splitting this controller in 2 fixed the recompilation loop...